# Wordpress yet another related posts plugin not outputting in specified location

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using the [YARPP](http://wordpress.org/plugins/yet-another-related-posts-plugin/) plugin for a custom hosted wordpress site. I've changed the default location settings so that it only displays the widget where I specify (see screenshot). When I call the plugin in my `single.php` file it is moving the widget inside of the `article.post`, even when I try and contain it in a separate wrapping div.

**single.php:**

```
<article class='post'>...</article>
<div class='yarpp-wrapper'>
    <?php if (function_exists('related_posts') ) : related_posts(); endif; ?>
</div>
```

**output:**
[image]

```
<article class='post'>...</article>
<div class='yarpp-related'>...</div> <!-- yarpp plugin-->
<div class='yarpp-wrapper></div> <!-- empty wrapper -->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you are using a custom yarpp template. Select 'List' instead, leave the other options above unchecked, and make sure the php script is in your single.php file. No need to wrap it in anything. Just place wherever you want it to show.

```
<?php related_posts(); ?>
```